# Devolver dos direcciones de memoria de un subproceso

Tags: array, c

Tengo este programa que debería determinar el mayor y el segundo mayor de un arreglo para mostrarlo en el subproceso mostrar, pero en lugar de hacer esto devuelve direcciones de memoria.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

// Declaraciones adelantadas de las funciones
void ingreso(float datos[], int n);
int ordenar(float datos[], int n, int *may1, int *may2);
void mostrar(int *may1, int *may2);

/* Busca los dos mayores de una lista de N datos */
int main() {
    float datos[200];
    int may1, may2, n;
    /* se pide al usuario ingresar la cantidad de datos,  */
    /* que no debera ser mayor a 200 */
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de datos (de 2 a 200):\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ingreso(datos,n);
    ordenar(datos,n,&may1,&may2);
    mostrar(&may1,&may2);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void ingreso(float datos[], int n) {
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=n-1;i++) {
        printf("Ingrese el dato %d:\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&datos[i]);
    }
}

int ordenar(float datos[], int n, int *may1, int *may2) {
    int i;
    if (datos[0]>datos[1]) {
        (*may1) = datos[0];
        (*may2) = datos[1];
    } else {
        (*may1) = datos[1];
        (*may2) = datos[0];
    }
    for (i=2;i<=n-1;i+=1) {
        if (datos[i]>(*may1)) {
            (*may2) = (*may1);
            (*may1) = datos[i];
        } else {
            if (datos[i]>(*may2)) {
                (*may2) = datos[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void mostrar(int *may1, int *may2) {
    printf("El mayor es: %d\n",may1);
    printf("El segundo mayor es: %d\n",may2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He cambiado un par de cosas para que funcionase.

Lo primero he cambiado el tipo de dato `float` a `int` en tu array `datos[]`

```
void ingreso(int datos[], int n);
//           ^^^
int ordenar(int datos[], int n, int *may1, int *may2);
//          ^^^
int main() {
    int datos[200];
//  ^^^
void ingreso(int datos[], int n) {
//           ^^^
int ordenar(int datos[], int n, int *may1, int *may2) {
//          ^^^
```

Lo segundo he cambiado el paso de parámetros por valor y no por referencia de tus variables `may1` y `may2` en la función `mostrar()`:

```
void mostrar(int may1, int may2);
//               ^^^        ^^^
mostrar(may1, may2);
//      ^^^   ^^^
void mostrar(int may1, int may2) {
//               ^^^       ^^^
```

Con esto conseguimos mostrar el valor de las dos variables.

**Código completo:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

// Declaraciones adelantadas de las funciones
void ingreso(int datos[], int n);
int ordenar(int datos[], int n, int *may1, int *may2);
void mostrar(int may1, int may2);

/* Busca los dos mayores de una lista de N datos */
int main() {
    int datos[200];
    int may1 = 0, may2 = 0, n = 0;
    /* se pide al usuario ingresar la cantidad de datos,  */
    /* que no debera ser mayor a 200 */
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de datos (de 2 a 200): ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ingreso(datos, n);
    ordenar(datos, n, &may1, &may2);
    mostrar(may1, may2);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void ingreso(int datos[], int n) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0;i <= n-1; i++) {
        printf("Ingrese el dato %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &datos[i]);
    }
}

int ordenar(int datos[], int n, int *may1, int *may2) {
    int i;

    if (datos[0] > datos[1]) {
        (*may1) = datos[0];
        (*may2) = datos[1];
    } else {
        (*may1) = datos[1];
        (*may2) = datos[0];
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        if (datos[i] > (*may1)) {
            (*may2) = (*may1);
            (*may1) = datos[i];
        } else {
            if (datos[i] > (*may2)) {
                (*may2) = datos[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void mostrar(int may1, int may2) {
    printf("El numero mayor es: %d\n", may1);
    printf("El segundo numero mayor es: %d\n", may2);
}
```

**EDICIÓN:**

Para utilizar la función `mostrar()` pasando como parámetros las variables por **referencia** hacemos lo siguiente:

```
//Declaración de la función

void mostrar(int *may1, int *may2);

//llamada a la funcion
//nota: inicializar las variables a 0 

int may1 = 0, may2 = 0, n;
mostrar(&may1,&may2);

//funcion

void mostrar(int *may1, int *may2) {
    printf("El mayor es: %d\n",*may1); //cambiamos el & por *
    printf("El segundo mayor es: %d\n",*may2); //cambiamos el & por *
}
```

**Código completo:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

// Declaraciones adelantadas de las funciones
void ingreso(int datos[], int n);
int ordenar(int datos[], int n, int *may1, int *may2);
void mostrar(int *may1, int *may2);

/* Busca los dos mayores de una lista de N datos */
int main() {
    int datos[200];
    int may1 = 0, may2 = 0, n;
    /* se pide al usuario ingresar la cantidad de datos,  */
    /* que no debera ser mayor a 200 */
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de datos (de 2 a 200):\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ingreso(datos,n);
    ordenar(datos,n,&may1,&may2);
    mostrar(&may1,&may2);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void ingreso(int datos[], int n) {
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=n-1;i++) {
        printf("Ingrese el dato %d:\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&datos[i]);
    }
}

int ordenar(int datos[], int n, int *may1, int *may2) {
    int i;
    if(n == 2){
        if (datos[0]>datos[1]) {
            (*may1) = datos[0];
            (*may2) = datos[1];
        } else {
            (*may1) = datos[1];
            (*may2) = datos[0];
        }
    }else{         
        for (i=0;i<=n-1;i+=1) {
            if (datos[i]>(*may1)) {
                (*may2) = (*may1);
                (*may1) = datos[i];
            } else {
                if (datos[i]>(*may2)) {
                    (*may2) = datos[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void mostrar(int *may1, int *may2) {
    printf("El mayor es: %d\n",*may1);
    printf("El segundo mayor es: %d\n",*may2);
}
```

Comment: ¿Y si yo quisiera que may1 y may2 sean de tipo float? ¿Hay alguna forma de que se pueda aplicar pasaje por puntero a un float?

Comment: Pues todo lo que sea int mencionando a las dos variables may1 y may2 ponerlos como float. De todas formas luego publico una edición de mi respuesta para que veas cómo quedaría.

Comment: Espero el código, pues hago lo que me has dicho pero me da de nuevo direcciones de memoria.

Comment: Ahora que estoy pensando no tiene sentido que may1 y may2 sean de tipo float si el arreglo es de tipo int (entero) Ya lo definí de tipo float y lo leí como float y anduvo bien. Por otro lado me queda la duda es porqué no pueden "desreferenciarse" las variables dentro del mostrar y deben entrar como variables limpias y no como pasajes por punteros.

Comment: Borro la edición de la variables en float y añado como seria la función mostrar() con las variables por referencias o sea punteros

Comment: Revisa la nueva edición! :)

Comment: Gracias por resolver el ejercico.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido!

Answer (score 1):

> Pero en lugar de hacer esto [determinar el mayor y el segundo mayor de un arreglo para mostrarlo] devuelve direcciones de memoria.

Obviamente, pues es lo que pides:

```
printf("El mayor es: %d\n",&may1);
//                         ^ <---- Dirección de 'may1'
printf("El segundo mayor es: %d\n",&may2);
//                                 ^ <---- Dirección de 'may2'
```

Si lo que quieres es mostrar el número, no muestres la dirección del puntero, muestra su contenido:

```
printf("El mayor es: %d\n",*may1);
//                         ^ <---- Contenido de 'may1'
printf("El segundo mayor es: %d\n",*may2);
//                                 ^ <---- Contenido de 'may2'
```